# React Native Android app minimizes and shows Launcher3

Tags: android, react-native

I have a relatively simple React Native (Android) app that sits in a lobby. It consists of 4 simple screens that allow a user to select his/her name, select a location on a map, then restart the process.

After running for about 5 days with regular use, the app crashes... Well, it doesn't actually crash. We're using Crashlytics and we don't receive a crash report and the app doesn't actually close; it just goes to the Overview screen and shows `Launcher3` (see image below).

[image: Launcher 3 bug]

I have no idea what could cause this error. Any idea what's causing this? Or at the very least, any suggestions on how I might go about debugging this?

- Hardware: Alcatel 9015B (Marshmallow)
- React Native: v0.42.3

Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "react": "15.5.4",
    "react-native": "0.42.3",
    "react-native-fabric": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "2.0.4",
    "react-native-maps": "0.13.1",
    "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "react-redux": "5.0.4",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "20.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.5.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

### Update

It's looking increasingly likely that this is a memory issue. Here is a snippet from the logs around the time the problems started happening:

```
[1077527.452315] binder: release 15127:15138 transaction 80204186 in, still active
[1077527.452330] binder: send failed reply for transaction 80204186 to 15092:15126
[1077527.459627] binder: 15092: binder_alloc_buf, no vma
[1077527.459644] binder: 980:3503 transaction failed 29201, size 88-4
[1077527.493244] binder: release 15141:15141 transaction 80204387 out, still active
[1077527.562781] binder: 980:5223 transaction failed 29189, size 1940-8
[1077527.562797] binder: send failed reply for transaction 80204387, target dead
[1077528.120965] lowmemorykiller: Killing 'e.process.gapps' (15171), adj 0,
[1077528.120965]    to free 37840kB on behalf of 'kswapd0' (111) because
[1077528.120965]    cache 13264kB is below limit 61440kB for oom_score_adj 0
[1077528.120965]    Free memory is 9376kB above reserved.
[1077528.120965]    Free CMA is 10300kB
[1077528.120965]    Total reserve is 21676kB
[1077528.120965]    Total free pages is 22100kB
[1077528.120965]    Total file cache is 136564kB
[1077528.120965]    Slab Reclaimable is 9452kB
[1077528.120965]    Slab UnReclaimable is 535236kB
[1077528.120965]    Total Slab is 544688kB
[1077528.120965]    GFP mask is 0xd0
[1077528.153006] lowmemorykiller: Killing '.gms.persistent' (15158), adj 0,
[1077528.153006]    to free 36220kB on behalf of 'kswapd0' (111) because
[1077528.153006]    cache 13016kB is below limit 61440kB for oom_score_adj 0
[1077528.153006]    Free memory is 9452kB above reserved.
[1077528.153006]    Free CMA is 10300kB
[1077528.153006]    Total reserve is 21676kB
[1077528.153006]    Total free pages is 27744kB
[1077528.153006]    Total file cache is 136788kB
[1077528.153006]    Slab Reclaimable is 9452kB
[1077528.153006]    Slab UnReclaimable is 535236kB
[1077528.153006]    Total Slab is 544688kB
[1077528.153006]    GFP mask is 0xd0
[1077528.179007] binder: 15158: binder_alloc_buf, no vma
[1077528.179024] binder: 980:994 transaction failed 29201, size 88-4
[1077531.534580] CHG: get_prop_capacity: soc samples[0] = 100
[1077531.534597] CHG: get_prop_capacity: soc samples[1] = 100
[1077531.534608] CHG: get_prop_capacity: soc samples[2] = 100
[1077531.534618] CHG: get_prop_capacity: soc samples[3] = 100
[1077531.537690] BMS_DEBUG 107535      16:28:30     4177573    100%    266C
[1077531.544665] CHG: get_prop_capacity: soc samples[0] = 100
[1077531.544680] CHG: get_prop_capacity: soc samples[1] = 100
[1077531.544691] CHG: get_prop_capacity: soc samples[2] = 100
[1077531.544700] CHG: get_prop_capacity: soc samples[3] = 100
[1077531.548164] CHG: get_prop_capacity: soc samples[0] = 100
[1077531.548178] CHG: get_prop_capacity: soc samples[1] = 100
[1077531.548188] CHG: get_prop_capacity: soc samples[2] = 100
[1077531.548197] CHG: get_prop_capacity: soc samples[3] = 100
[1077537.472422] type=1400 audit(1496766516.553:45833): avc: denied { search } for pid=2370 comm="ndroid.systemui" name="15206" dev="proc" ino=12174739 scontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
[1077537.472735] type=1400 audit(1496766516.553:45834): avc: denied { search } for pid=2370 comm="ndroid.systemui" name="15206" dev="proc" ino=12174739 scontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
[1077537.472999] type=1400 audit(1496766516.553:45835): avc: denied { search } for pid=2370 comm="ndroid.systemui" name="15206" dev="proc" ino=12174739 scontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
[1077541.017542] init: Service 'atfwd' (pid 9821) exited with status 255
[1077541.017582] init: Service 'atfwd' (pid 9821) killing any children in process group
[1077541.018827] init: Starting service 'atfwd'...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by a known memory leak in the core Android operating system for Marshmallow. It's just the way it is and they don't intend to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Few days back i faced the similar issue i resolved it by simply deleting node_modules and then installed the fresh node_modules or if you are running yarn then please run `yarn upgrade`.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that :/ unfortunately the problem takes several days of use to materialize, so it's hard to replicate consistently. I currently have 5 apps running next to me, hoping that one of them breaks :D

Comment: Yes, it's currently on-device built for release.